How to query a GORM Domain with a hasMany enum relationship to find entries containing only specific Enum values?
I'm working with a Grails application where I have a domain class that has a hasMany relationship with an enum. Here’s a simplified version of the code:
class Domain {
    static hasMany = [
        flags: Flags
    ]
}

enum Flags {
    VALUE, OTHER_VALUE
}

I need to write a GORM query that finds all Domain instances where the flags collection contains only the OTHER_VALUE enum value.

How can I correctly formulate a GORM query that returns Domain instances where the flags collection only contains the OTHER_VALUE enum?

Is there a specific way to handle hasMany relationships with enums in GORM that I’m missing?


Looking for something like
Domain.where {
   flags.contains(Flag.VALUE)
}.list()

however, the above isn't okay.

I don't have a setup for testing this now, so just adding as a comment.  Wouldn't it work to do something like Domain.where { flags == [Flag.VALUE]) }?  You could also check that size == 1 and contains VALUE but that seems a little hacky.

Hey, "contains" actually doesn't work, that was one of the things I tried, as depicted in the question. As for your suggestion 1. it doesn't work, I tried just now 2. even if it worked it would be problematic, because there can be many flags in our real prod case and I need to check for a presence of one, not an equality check of the entire set.

At first I thought HQL would be the simple answer on this but after giving it a shot, based on your current domain setup you will get unmapped table errors since DOMAIN_FLAGS isn't actually defined.
Instead I dropped down to create a native SQL statement. This is the method I ended up with. You'll need the sessionFactory injected.
List<Domain> sqlQuery() {
    def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
    def sql = """select d.* from domain d
        where d.id in (
            select domain_id from DOMAIN_FLAGS
            group by domain_id
            having count(*) = 1 and max(flags) = 'OTHER_VALUE'
        )"""

    session.createSQLQuery(sql)
            .setParameter('flag', Flags.OTHER_VALUE.toString())
            .addEntity(Domain)
            .list()
}


Thanks a lot for your answer. Yeah, I knew I could resort to direct sql statements. However, I thought it would be really strange that such a very basic thing to query wouldn't be supported and would require direct sql. Are you affiliated in some way with the tech, or is there still some hope there's a higher level approach for this we just don't know about?

I've been using GORM for around 10 years. I'm not a contributor to it.
While the query itself is simple, it’s complex from an ORM perspective because it requires a mix of grouping, aggregation, and filtering on a collection. This is why GORM doesn’t have a straightforward, high-level method for this particular scenario without resorting to SQL.
By explicitly mapping the Flags table you could use a few other options such as GORM criteria and HQL
Some ORMs have a SQL like expressive syntax to handle this. But at that point, you are basically writing SQL and not as abstracted.

Thanks a lot for the context, you helped us make a decision on how to move forward. It also invites the idea that we'd introduce instead a simple domain class that would only hold that enum, to enforce it as a true association of two domain objects in one to many fashion. Just a thought. If it would mean significantly less performance, sql could work. What I don't like about sql is that it's more fragile to maintain in case of some renamings happen and such. Those are however infrequent, so maybe it's fine.
